# MacBook Air 2009 using too much battery during sleep - Too old?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, sleep-wake

I have just bought a MacBook Air Mid 2009 and i'm surprised about the speed it uses battery during sleep.

Here are the technical features :

- MacBook Air 13" Mid 2009   (MacBookAir2,1)
- Mountain Lion 10.8.5
- Intel Core 2 Duo 1.86
- 2GB RAM

The battery has **528** cycles.

When I use it correctly and gently, it is quite slow but still works fine. 
The battery lasts around **3 hours**.

The problem is that when i close the lid, and it goes to sleep, the battery is still draining at a rate of **4%** per hour (based on several tests I have made).

Which means that it can go from 90% to 10% if I just let it sleep during one full day without charging it.

I have checked the **light pulse** and it is ok (gentle pulse), I have checked the **syslog** and it doesn't Wake during the night, I have checked the **pmset** and everything is ok (value : 3), I have made **reset of SMC and PRAM**.

Do you think it's a **correct behaviour with an old battery** ? or is there an issue about it ?

Comment: Yeah, that seems about right, based on anecdotal experience with my 2008 MacBook.

Comment: @JMY1000 I have ordered a new battery .. it seems there's nothing to do with soft solutions .. It's too old and has too many cycles. Thanks for your experience !

Comment: just changed the battery .. almost the same .. it loses 3% per hour .. I don't know what to do

Comment: It's an old computer that consumes a lot of power, even when idle. TBH, though that seems a tab bit high, it's not too far out of the norm.